# Visual Studio alternative for PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio, ide

I have earlier worked on Visual Studio and am pretty much comfortable in using that. 
But now I have some programming work in PHP.
Is there any plug in available that I can install on Visual Studio 2008/2010 and program in PHP/MySQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Commercial you have: 
[Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/products/studio/) wich is pretty powerfull.

[Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) is pretty good too

Of course [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) (Zend Studio is built on it). Now free!

[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) is lighter but very fast and practical I love it.

There are much lighter editors out there like textedit but if you want something like visual studio Zend/Eclipse is a good bet.

As for pluguins I guess I was wrong and there is http://www.jcxsoftware.com/ as pointed out by Sem Dendoncker. Seems pretty interresting I am downloading the trial now. But I am a cheap and love my free editors.

Comment: Isn't Zend Studio built on Eclipse, like Aptana? Anyway, the last version I tested ZS 6.x was terrible - full of bugs. Like it was done without any QA. I'm not sure they improved it much since then. Make sure you test it thoroughly before purchasing.

Comment: @Vikash yeah I am a BIG netbeans fan. Becoming an evangelist too. :)

Comment: I am not mad at the downvote but what is bad with my answer? So the other one is more popular so vote for it. I think I posted a perfectly valid opinion offering options that are valid. Anyways.

Comment: well, you get a +1 from me to even thigs out for recommending NB :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Codecharge Studio 5 which supports code generation, php and javascript events and direct connectivity with artisteer's templates.

There is also a CMS based on Codecharge Studio that supports most of contemporary CMS functions. You can use Codecharge Studio to add more functions or just use its free version and build your own site. Visit www.krisonav.com

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Devsense's PHP for a couple of months and it has been a live saver. Breakpoints, debug, variable visualization all within that familiar and fast environment of VS. It's a bit buggy, doesn't visualize SimpleXMLElements real well, at times won't scroll through inline javascript but it's helped me so much.

Notepad++, even with debug is a far cry from VS.  Notepad++'s autocomplete is very slow, VS does pretty good.

I'm using it for WordPress and it does fine, with the exception that (for speed) I've excluded the WP core from the project.